# ¿Como hago, en wordpress, un enlace para un logueo por URL?

Tags: wordpress

**¿Como hago, en wordpress, un enlace para un logueo por URL?**

Quiero decir, mi idea es que a un determinado usuario, digamos cliente_potencial pueda ver una tabla de precios que se encuentra privada, pero como este aún no es un cliente registrado, la pueda ver mediante un acceso que yo envíe por whatsapp o por correo, obviamente, este usuario solo podría acceder a la información pública y a está página privada en concreto, nada más.

Una URL del tipo: [misitio.com/wp-admin?log=username&pwd=password](http://misitio.com/wp-admin?log=username&pwd=password)

**¿Alguien lo ha intentado? ¿Se puede hacer? ¿Qué riesgos implica?**

Buscando en ingles, conseguí este código:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['username']) and $_GET['pass'] ) {
    $user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['username']);

    if ( $user && wp_check_password( $_GET['pass'], $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) {
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);

        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit;
    }

    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
?>
```

Pero no lo entiendo del todo y por esto no me ha funcionado, creo. 
Mi idea es que el usuario sea: 
"cotizante" 
y la contraseña: 
"Cotización2019"

o algo así...

**pd:** *Depronto la pregunta es muy novata, sorry.*

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación oficial de Wordpress?

Comment: Si y no, estoy siempre aprendiendo lo de los temas a través de un canal en youtube y en los foros, pero mi conocimiento en php y programación, es más bien básico.

Comment: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/phpya/ evoluciona :D

Comment: Gracias por enlace, voy a estudiarlo mucho, sobre todo porque tiene un temario bastante básico pero va escalando muy bien, al menos para mi que no he recibido ninguna formación en desarrollo o programación xD, pero ahora tengo es una duda muy puntual, tienes alguna documentación, en inglés o en español, sobre este tema, pero que de verdad funcione o al menos que explique bien como se debe hacer y que recomendaciones sobre seguridad hay sobre el tema.

Comment: Está mal planteada... Básicamente un GET es para RECIBIR información, un POST es para ENVIAR información, un GET te va a dar un formulario y un POST va a enviar esos datos al servidor para que se validen y genere un login. Revisa: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ y https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth utiliza https://www.deepl.com/translator como traductor. Tu sitio en wordpress FIJO tiene que TENER un certificado SSL y hacer peticiones HTTPS.

Comment: Digamos lo plantie mal, ya modifique la pregunta, lo que quiero es lograr que por medio de una URL, tipo: ´´misitio.com/wp-admin?log=username&pwd=password´´ se de un acceso.

Comment: ¿Todavía no lees los enlaces verdad?

Answer (score 0):

Más que dar un enlace con el usuario y la contraseña en él (que pueden copiarlo y entrar a wordpress de normal si son un poco listos), yo lo que haría es hacer una pagina que no este pública a ojos de google (que no la indexe) y que no esté en tu menú. De esta manera, si no es con el enlace nadie podrá verla.